# Keychain item shared when access group is not set

Tags: ios, keychain

I have two applications using the same schema to store an kSecClassGenericPassword item protected by a biometric authentication.

After the initializations of the applications, I am not able to retrieve the content of the keychain item from one application (errSecInteractionNotAllowed = -25308) when all is good for the other.

The behaviour is as the keychain item is shared between the two applications even if the keychain access group is not set.

I put a sample app and a video on this folder: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lk5p1war4c4tids/AACbE-E-z7Pqjx9XHD92RJ6Sa?dl=0

Steps to Reproduce (See the video as attachments):

- Use the Keychain-Access project provided
- Set the bundle identifier: App1 -> ch.sysmosoft.debug.Keychain-Access.1
- Launch App1
- Close App1
- Launch App1
- Authenticate
- Protected element is presented
- Change the bundle identifier: App2 -> ch.sysmosoft.debug.Keychain-Access.2
- Launch App2
- Close App2
- Launch App2
- Protected element is presented
- Launch App1
- Protected element is not accessible (errSecInteractionNotAllowed)

Version/Build:

- Xcode -> Version 10.1 (10B61)
- iOS -> 12.1 (16B92)
- iPhone 6s (model MKQN2ZD/A)
- iPad mini (model ME276GP/A)

Other information:

This bug occurs even if the TeamId is different.

I use the keychain item unique identifier from this page [What makes a keychain item unique (in iOS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614047/what-makes-a-keychain-item-unique-in-ios)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the source of the error.

To solve the issue with the keychain item protected by biometrical authentication, you must have a **different** `PRODUCT_NAME`.